# How do I move a Wordpress website from one host to another?

Tags: wordpress

I'm completely new to web development, I have general computer knowledge. I'm trying to fix this issue by myself: I need to move a website to a different hosting space and domain.

I don't have access to the original website server, just the account to the WordPress admin page used to make the website. I used the WordPress plugin `duplicator` to export a copy of the website since who the original dev couldn't send it to me.

I uploaded all the files via ftp to the new host, keeping the same structure.

Then I used the phpMyAdmin tool that came with the new hosting service and I imported the SQL database. Since it's not published yet, I modified the host file in Windows pointing the new website to the right url, and tried to open it with my browser.

I get `Error setting up a connection to the database`, and looking in the logs folder on the server, in the file error_log i see `GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 266`.

Can anyone tell me if i'm missing some essential steps, or what is the problem?

Comment: You need to configure the new credentials for the database in the new host server. Them are username, password, server and database name. I think that's in the wp-config.php file, but I don't know exactly right now

Comment: If you need to migrate an install to another install, check out WP Clone: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-clone-by-wp-academy/

So long as you can log in as an admin on both installs, it will clone the environment completely, users, posts, pages, everything. I will destroy everything on the target install so be careful if you need to keep anything on the target install.

It also sounds like you are attempting to copy the wp-config.php file, which contains all the DB connectivity information. It's likely attempting to use the OLD database instead of the new one you are setting up.

Comment: Additionally, make sure that the versions are the same if you are dropping files in selectively on the installation. You could be having file compatibility issues depending on which version you are coming from and moving to.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because WordPress is unable to establish a database connection.

It could be that your database login credentials are wrong.

Edit `wp-config.php` file and find and update these entries.

```
define('DB_NAME', 'database-name');
define('DB_USER', 'database-username');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'database-password');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

to match your new host database access details

Answer (score 0):

The Duplicator plugin is not able to read the database connection details at the new webhost and edit `wp-config.php` by itself. You set up the new database at the new webhost - or it was already created by the host - and you must change the database name, user name and password (and possibly the database connection URL, but which is almost always `localhost`) in `wp-config.php` to match the database connection details at the new host. Look in the Cpanel of the new host and in PHPMyAdmin to find those details.

And see [Editing wp-config.php « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php)